# There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 36,Token in error = Name ]

Tags: visual-studio, vb.net-2010

I want to get the user input from different textboxes, labels and combo boxes and then insert it into the data grid with SQL CE 3.5, I tried putting them into variables as a string but still I'm having issues with this code:

```
Private Sub addToDb_btn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles addToDb_btn.Click
    Dim IDVal As String = accIdVal_Lbl.Text
    Dim Pwrd As String = accPassVal_Lbl.Text
    Dim AcTp As String = accTyp_Cbx.Text
    Dim FNm As String = accFrstNm_Txbx.Text
    Dim MNm As String = accMidNm_Txbx.Text
    Dim LNm As String = accLstNm_Txbx.Text
    Dim UsrNm As String = accUsrNm_Txbx.Text
    cmd = New SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO userAccounts(ID, First Name, Middle Name, Last Name, Username, Password, Account Type) VALUES('" & IDVal & "',  '" & FNm & "',  '" & MNm & "',  '" & LNm & "',  '" & UsrNm & "',  '" & Pwrd & "', '" & AcTp & "')", con)
    If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then con.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    con.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you explain what kind of problems?

Comment: The error I'm receiving is in the title. It seems I'm problems while inserting records with the SqlCeCommand

Answer (score 0):

Enclose identifiers in []:

```
INSERT INTO [userAccounts]([ID], [First Name], [Middle Name], [Last Name], [Username], [Password], [Account Type]
```